# How to separate hoverlabel property of x and y in Plotly

Tags: javascript, plotly

how to separate hoverlabel property of x and y? How to make x hoverlabel stick to bottom in plotly javascript as like on the picture?[image: What im want to do]

Actually i done this, but hoverlabel has coupled x and y value.

```
var data = [
{
type: 'scatter',
x: [],
y: [],type: 'scatter',
line: {                             
width: 2,
color: '#D2AB67'
}

}
];

var layout = {
plot_bgcolor: '#F7F8FA',
paper_bgcolor: '#F7F8FA',
showlegend: false,


yaxis: {
title: 'Kurs złota PLN/1oz',
showgrid: false,
linecolor: 'black',
linewidth: 1,
mirror: true
},

xaxis: {
showgrid: false,
linecolor: 'black',
linewidth: 1,
mirror: true
}


};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {displayModeBar: false});
```

[image: What i acutally do]

I was searching documentation, but but i didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`hovermode`](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/layout/#layout-hovermode) accordingly in the layout settings.

> **hovermode** - ( "x" | "y" | "closest" | false | "x unified" | "y unified" ). Default: "closest".
> Determines the mode of hover interactions. If "closest", a single
> hoverlabel will appear for the "closest" point within the
> `hoverdistance`. If "x" (or "y"), multiple hoverlabels will appear for
> multiple points at the "closest" x- (or y-) coordinate within the
> `hoverdistance` [...].

```js
const layout : {
  hovermode: 'x',
  // ...
};
```